# Convert this pattern to regex for Pattern.matches(..)

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching

Some of my strings may contain a substring that looks like `@[alph4Num3ric-alph4Num3ric]` , where I will find the alpha numberic id and replace it with a corresponding text value mapped to the associated key in a map.

My first inclination was to check if my `string.contains("@[")` but I want to be more specific

so now I am looking at `Pattern.matches(` but am unsure of the regex and total expression

how would I regex for @[ ...... - .... ] in the Pattern.matches method, it must also account for dashes. So I'm not sure what needs to be escaped in this syntax or wildcarded, or more.

I am also not 100% sure if this is the best message. I want to get a boolean from Pattern.matches first, and then get the real value and modify the string with those values, which seems good enough, but I want to minimize computations.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Can you please share your attempts?

Comment: Wow, almost 10K reputation; and still you post a question just giving requirements; without showing any code ...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what do you think about the approach?

Comment: @GhostCat sure, when you use the java or javascript tag you attract a lot of jaded people that are tired of 0 rep people posting homework questions, but I primarily don't use those tags and other communities are actually really helpful in solving abstract problems. Other people find those questions helpful based on the utility and you get 10k rep, so it is easy to forget that `java` tag followers have imagined a higher bar for questions here.

Comment: It is easy: if you need to validate format, use `.matches`. If you need to replace, use `replaceAll`/`replaceFirst`.

Comment: After reading your comments I think you need `@\\[(\\w+(?:-\\w+)+)]` for `matches`, but not sure what you need for replacement. Note the capturin group inside `@[`...`]` that backreferenced to with `$1`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew a little bit of yours and the other answers all helped! thank you

Comment: If you wanted immediate and relevant help, you could provide at least 1 test case with sample input, expected output, and what you've tried (some code that would be easily debugged). You asked a question 12 hrs ago, and finally came up with a solution 6 hrs ago - it took you 6 hrs while it could take 6 minutes. Next time, please invest more time to your question. Considering you might want to also increase your reputation.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew didn't take six hours, the regex I asked for here was only an example and I changed it to match the problem I had within minutes of getting some suggestions here, and then that was only a small part of the problem. I wanted an efficient answer to keep my actual solution fairly efficient, instead of trying to reinvent the wheel. I can't post my actual problems here, you'll get over it soon enough. I only replied to you to thank you, not to give an accurate picture of when I finished the problem (who does that?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plese try this ,

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String expression = "String contains @[alph4Num3ric-alph4Num3ric] as substring";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern
                .compile("\\@\\[([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(expression);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("matched: "+matcher.group());
            System.out.println("group1: "+matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println("group2: "+matcher.group(2));
            System.out
                    .println("after replace "+expression.replace(matcher.group(1), "customkey"));
        }
    }

}
```

output :

```
matched: @[alph4Num3ric-alph4Num3ric]
group1: alph4Num3ric
group2: alph4Num3ric
after replace: String contains @[customkey-customkey] as substring
```

Comment: Why are you escaping `@`?

Comment: both ways it works,  you can remove escape before @ , generally I don't take chances for special characters :)

Comment: There can be multiple dashes, so is there a way I can just match for the existence of just @[ ..... ] ? In some regex processors I use \w+ but I feel like that fails because of the variety of characters too. I will be replacing @[] too

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
/@[(a-zA-Z0-9-)+]/
```

I haven't given it a try but hope this would help. Also if it returns an error then add a backward slash between 9 and - e.g.  /@[(a-zA-Z0-9-)+]/

Comment: There can be multiple dashes, so is there a way I can just match for the existence of just @[ ..... ] ? In some regex processors I use `\w+` but I feel like that fails because of the variety of characters too

Comment: May be like this /@[(a-zA-Z0-9-)+]/

also if it returns an error then add a backward slash between 9 and - e.g.  /@[(a-zA-Z0-9\-)+]/

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment.